# Render JSON array of strings from one DB column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, controller, rendering

I've researched other JSON rendering issues here, but I haven't found any that are looking to end up with an array. I found many posts about rendering as hash, but they haven't been helpful.

Recent attempts include:

```
def create
  params[:_json].each do |ip|
    IpAddress.create(ip: ip)
  end

  ips = IpAddress.pluck(:ip)

  ips.each do |ips|
    ips.to_s
  end

  render json: ips
end
```

As well as

```
def create
  params[:_json].each do |ip|
    IpAddress.create(ip: ip)
  end
  render json: IpAddress.all, methods: [:ip]     
end
```

Both of these attempts return the entire array of database rows.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `ips = IpAddress.pluck(:ip)` and then `render json: { ips: ips }` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, my def create action was a non-issue. It was rendering properly, but the problem was that my test was failing because after creating, it was hitting the index action to see if the array was saved properly. So, I added

```
  def index
    render json: IpAddress.pluck(:ip)
  end
```

And my test passed.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: oO at least asking the question helped to solve your problem.

Comment: That's exactly it! I've spent HOURS on this, and 10 minutes after adding my question I figured it out. SO etiquette:  should I accept my own answer and leave it up (so maybe it helps someone else) or just delete the entire question?

Comment: Sorry, nevermind. Per Meta, you can't delete once other answers are provided.

Comment: self answers are not frowned upon either way. Just leave it here.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in general.
Just building the array up while creating the database entries and then return it.

```
def create
  ips = params[:_json].inject([]) do |a, ip|
    a << IpAddress.create!(ip: ip).ip
    a
  end
  render json: {ips: ips}
end
```